# Как из бд вывести дату в формате 01.11.1991? python

Tags: python

Мне нужно вывести дату из бд в формате 08.12.2021

```js
def get_reg_date(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
             return self.cursor.execute("SELECT `date_registration` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
```

При выводе получаю [('2021-12-07 15:50:24.069053',)]

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
with self.connection:
    self.cursor.execute("SELECT `date_registration` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,))
    for row in self.cursor.fetchall():
        print(f"{row[0]:%d.%m.%Y}")
```